# Is api.example.com better than example.com/api?

Tags: php, ruby, api, rest, subdomain

It seems like the majority of the popular RESTful APIs prefer subdomains over subdirectories:

- api.twitter.com
- api.linkedin.com
- api.foursquare.com
- graph.facebook.com

I was wondering if there are any technical arguments behind that.

Comment: One reason I can think of is that you can route the API requests to a different server using DNS with the subdomain method instead of having to use a proxy or load-balancer when `/api` is used.  This is especially important for very large volume APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a load balancing thing.

> twitter.com has address 199.59.150.39
> twitter.com has address 199.59.149.230
> twitter.com has address 199.59.150.7
> api.twitter.com has address 199.59.150.9
> api.twitter.com has address 199.59.149.232
> api.twitter.com has address 199.59.148.20
> api.twitter.com has address 199.59.148.87
>
> api.linkedin.com has address 216.52.242.83
> linkedin.com has address 216.52.242.86
>
> api.foursquare.com has address 50.19.210.39
> foursquare.com has address 50.16.220.173
>
> graph.facebook.com has address 66.220.146.87
> facebook.com has address 66.220.158.11
> facebook.com has address 69.171.229.11
> facebook.com has address 69.171.242.11
> facebook.com has address 66.220.149.11

It really helps stability when you separate web from API at the client instead of a proxy. For example, Twitter's own site runs on Ruby, while the backends are primarily written in Scala. A proxy could route those two, but it would need a lot of connections to both the API and the main site, resulting in a connection pool that's twice as large.

Another advantage is that when your API goes down, the site will still work (doesn't apply to Twitter, as the site is built on top of the API).

Answer (score 0):

Something to take in to consideration is cross-domain AJAX calls.  If you're on a site `domain.com` you can't make AJAX calls to `sub.domain.com`.

Comment: Sure you can. Put [`document.domain='domain.com';`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain) on top of both files and your browser will treat them both as if they're on `domain.com`. You could also use JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want API Service use another server (large scale) `api.domain.com` is better, but you want AJAX in medium or small scale `domain.com/api` is better.

Comment: AJAX works to subdomains although it requires a small `document.domain` hack.